# How can I control the number of categories in the treemap package?

Tags: r, treemap

In the example below treemap produces automatically 8 categories for “employees”. How could I change that i.e. to 4 categories? And could I also set the ranges of the categories?
Thanks

```
library(treemap)

data(business)

treemap(business,
        index=c("NACE1", "NACE2"),
        vSize="employees",
        vColor="employees",
        title.legend="number of employees",
        type="value")
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your question. It is not (yet?) possible to change the number of categories for a quantitative treemap. However, you can create a categorical treemap:

```
library(treemap)
data(business)
business <- transform(business, empCat = cut(employees, breaks = c(0, 3000, 6000, 9000, 
    14000), include.lowest = TRUE, right=FALSE))

treemap(business,
    index=c("NACE1", "NACE2"),
    vSize="employees",
    vColor="empCat",
    type="categorical", 
    palette="Greens",
    title.legend="number of employees",
    position.legend = "bottom")
```

Comment: As of version 2.3 (on github, and on CRAN very soon), there is an argument n for the number of categories.